# Will it be harmful if there are two almost same richsnippets on 2 different pages

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

Will it be harmful if I put two almost same rich snippets on two different pages?

For example, I have organization preview and contact pages.

The richsnippet on preview page is:

```
{
    "@context":  "http://schema.org",
    "@type":     "Organization",
    "legalName": "test name",
    "url":       "some url",
    "email":     "some email",
    "address":  {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "City, Country",
        "postalCode":      "16000",
        "streetAddress":   "Test street address"
    }
}
```

The richsnippet on contact page is:

```
{
    "@context":  "http://schema.org",
    "@type":     "Organization",
    "legalName": "test name",
    "url":       "some url",
    "address":  {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "City, Country",
        "postalCode":      "16000",
        "streetAddress":   "Test street address"
    },
    "contactPoint": [
        {
            "@type":     "ContactPoint",
            "telephone": "123123",
            "faxNumber": "123123",
            "email":     "some email",
            "contactType": "customer service"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no reason to assume that this would be problematic.

It’s expected that you provide the data for the current document’s content, and if two pages state something about the same thing, but one page has, e.g., its telephone number, and the other page not, then this is exactly what you get: two different representations for the same entity.

Because you are using the `url` property, consumers could deduce that these items are about the same thing. (Even I, on a totally different site, could provide additional properties about *your* entity, by using the same `url` value.)

Answer (score 0):

You might provide a URI for the described organization as both snippets are about the same thing.

You can use **JSON-LD: @id** in this case.